# The jQuery selector with context doesn't work

Tags: jquery, selector

I expect this code will change the text only on last div (Div5), but it doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".blue", "#Div5").text("Hello");
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <div id="Div1" class="blue">AAAA</div>
    <div id="Div2" class="yellow">BBBB</div>
    <div id="Div3" class="blue">CCCC</div>
    <div id="Div4" class="yellow">DDDD</div>
    <div id="Div5" class="blue">EEEE</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Does anybody happen to know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is used for specifying a container element. In your example, you are referencing the same element in the context as your selector.

You can simplify to this:

```
$("#Div5").text("Hello");
```

Or, if you still want to explicitly specify the class:

```
$("#Div5.blue").text("Hello");
```

Both will have the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm beginner in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

That's looking for a .blue within the div, and is semantically equivalent to

```
$("#Div5").find(".blue").text("Hello");
```

You want:

```
$("#Div5.blue").text("Hello");
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
if ($("#Div5").hasClass("blue")) {
    $("#Div5").text("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe so?

```
$("#Div5").text("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the context (i.e. the *container*) in this case. You should target your elements like this:

```
$("#Div5.blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need simply

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Div5").text("Hello");
});
```

What you tried to do is find a tag with class `blue` *within* the tag with id 'Div5'. Since there are no nested divs, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a context selector as they are both the same element in your html

```
 $(".blue", "#Div5")
```

means select the .blue item that is a child of #div5

so the html for that would be

```
<div id="div5">
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

you simply need $('#div5").text('text');

Answer (score 0):

I think the context parameter has to be a jQuery object, or at the very least a HTMLDOMElement (or whatever they're called. :P)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $contextElement = jQuery("#Div5");
    jQuery(".blue", $contextElement).text("Hello");
});
```

Though, judging from your markup, I'd say that you don't want to use context at all, but just selector, like so:

```
jQuery("#Div5").text("woop woop!");
```

You don't even need to target the `blue`class, since the ID is unique. In fact, even if you had two elements with the ID `Div5` jQuery would only return one, the first one.